# net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr) security in go

Tags: go, ip

My server relies on IP filtering for security. I was wondering if someone can bypass protections that relies on remote IP filtering using `net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr)`

For that I created this dummy http server:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
)

func getHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("got /hello request\n")
    host, _, _ := net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr)
    fmt.Printf("Ip is %s\n", host)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", getHello)

    http.ListenAndServe(":3333", nil)
}
```

I did then some test with curl:

```
curl http://localhost:3333/hello 
<- Logs in my server -> Ip is 127.0.0.1

curl http://localhost:3333/hello -H "X-Forwarded-For: 3.3.3.3" -H "Host: 3.3.3.3"
<- Logs in my server -> Ip is 127.0.0.1
```

It seems secure as I was not able to trick my server of thinking the IP of the request is `3.3.3.3`.

Is `r.RemoteAddr` really secure and looks for the IP inside the TCP packet ? Or is there a way to bypass it by using header or forging packets ?

Comment: According to docs [here](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request), `RemoteAddr field is ignored by the HTTP client.` It's only set by `HTTP server` by reading `Source Address` in `IP` packet. `Host` & `X-Forwarded-For` are `http` headers which are only passed after `TCP` handshake. So, your `HTTP` server has already got the `RemoteAddr` before such info is passed in `headers` after successful handshake.

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs [here](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request),

> RemoteAddr field is ignored by the HTTP client.

It's only set by HTTP server by reading `Source Address` in `IP` packet.

`Host` & `X-Forwarded-For` are `http` headers which are only passed after TCP handshake. So, your HTTP server has already got the `RemoteAddr` before such info is passed in headers after successful handshake.

Answer (score 0):

Expecting the remote address to be changed by setting HTTP headers shows fundamental misunderstanding about how the TCP/IP stack works. That's OK - it just makes the question hard to answer.

`http.Request.RemoteAddr` is populated from the IP packet's header field: "source ip address"

While it is possible to craft packets with arbitrary values in this header field, establishing a TCP session requires a three-way handshake. If the server tried to reply to a host that doesn't have a matching `active-open` session, it'll get rejected.

> It seems secure as I was not able to trick my server of thinking the IP of the request is 3.3.3.3.

For your knowledge, the two headers you set are well-known.

1. `Host` is required and used to specify which *server* you are intending the request to go to: [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host)
2. `X-Forwarded-For` is a common header for proxies: [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For)

While the latter, if present, can be used to know the original client's IP address... it's still a header. It's up to the application to interpret it.

Comment: Do you have source for that claim please `http.Request.RemoteAddr is populated from the IP packet's header field: "source ip address"`

Comment: @RudeusGreyrat Start here and work your way around. It comes from net.Conn.RemoteAddr: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/server.go#L270

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/server.go#L1889 and https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/server.go#L264

Comment: If you doubt that `net.Conn` itself is populated from that, then feel free to follow it all the way down. The Go source code is fairly readable.